# Safecracker Registration - Documentation on Hooks

Tags: safecracker-registration

In the [changelog](https://www.objectivehtml.com/safecracker-registration/changelog), I see that developer hooks was added as a feature in 1.2.0

But looking that [documentation](https://www.objectivehtml.com/safecracker-registration/documentation), I don't see any thing about hooks.

Is there any place or site that can point me to Safecracker Registration Hooks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No docs on this stuff at this time. I added those a while a back and forgot to include them in the docs. They are pretty straight forward though. If you want me to help you with anything specifically, email support@objectivehtml.com.

I will add this documentation to my list of to-do's and hopefully have this updated this week. So in the meantime, just email me for quick assistance.